# On firing Ajax from dropdown, previous row elements are getting changed

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using PHP and Ajax with Javascript. I don't want to use jQuery here.

I have multiple rows added dynamically with two dropdowns in each row. Problem is that any change made in the second or subsequent row effects the elements of first row instead of their own row.

I have two drop downs.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-2">
            <label for="fn">Firm Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" name='dealer_firm[]' id="dealer_firm" onchange="get_dealer_name(this.value)" required>
            <option value="">Select Firm</option>
                <?php 
                    $sql20=$con->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT firm_name FROM dealers');
                    $sql20->execute();
                    $result20=$sql20->get_result();
                    if($result20->num_rows>0)
                    {
                        while($rows20=$result20->fetch_object())
                        {
                            echo "<option value='". $rows20->firm_name ."'>".$rows20->firm_name;
                        }   
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-2">
            <label for="dn">Dealer Name</label>
            <div id="dn_options">
                <select class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On selecting a value in first dropdown, second drop down populates with new values using AJAX.

**AJAX:**

```
function get_dealer_name(frm)
{   
var msgbox=document.getElementById('mymsg');
if(msgbox==null){}
else
    msgbox.style.display='none';
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{  
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("dn_options").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","Dealer_Name.php?q1="+frm,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**Code for Dealer_Name.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['q1']))
{
    $f=$_GET['q1'];
    $sql20=$con->prepare('SELECT sno,dealer_name FROM dealers WHERE firm_name=?');
    $sql20->bind_param('s', $f);
    $sql20->execute();
    $result20=$sql20->get_result();
    if($result20->num_rows>0)
    {
        echo '<select class="form-control" name="dealer_name[]" id="dealer_name" required>';
        echo "<option value='selectdealer'>Select Dealers</option>";
        while($rows20=$result20->fetch_object())
        {
            echo "<option value='". $rows20->sno ."'>".$rows20->dealer_name;
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

This much works fine.

Now, I have an Add More Rows Button which will add up more rows with the same dropdowns for next selection.

```
function add_newrow()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
        var list = document.querySelectorAll(".newretrow");
        var last = list[list.length - 1];
        last.innerHTML=this.responseText;

        var list = document.querySelectorAll(".newretrow");
        var last = list[list.length - 1];
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute("class", "row newretrow");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newretrow");
        newDiv.innerHTML = "";
        last.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","Add_New_Row.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Add_New_Row.php**

```
<div class="col col-sm-2">
<label for="fn">Firm Name</label>
<select class="form-control" name='dealer_firm[]' id="dealer_firm" onchange="get_dealer_name(this.value)" required>
<option value="">Select Firm</option>
    <?php 
        $sql20=$con->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT firm_name FROM dealers');
        $sql20->execute();
        $result20=$sql20->get_result();
        if($result20->num_rows>0)
        {
            while($rows20=$result20->fetch_object())
            {
                echo "<option value='". $rows20->firm_name ."'>".$rows20->firm_name;
            }   
        }
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col col-sm-2">
  <label for="dn">Dealer Name</label>
    <div id="dn_options">
        <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

In the newly added row, when I select something from first dropdown, it should change the value of *second drop down of second row* but it changes the value of *second drop down in the first row rather than the second row*. The elements of same row should get affected.

> Please suggest some solution with Javascript, Not Jquery.

Comment: Why tag jQuery if you do not want jQuery? Also jQuery would make your life a lot easier in this case

Comment: @mplungjan Because most of the time JQuery developers are Javascript experts, so they might be able to help me out. The reason behind not using JQuery is that the system already relies heavily on Javascript here. I dont want to mix up two strategies.

Comment: That is a very sneaky way to abuse tags. I will edit your tags. Also your issue without looking at your reams of code is likely duplicate IDs. IDs MUST be unique

Comment: You did not post get_brands

Comment: @mplungjan In complete system, are 8-9 dropdowns changed together, posting whole code would be too large and not useful. If things go fine in two dropdown, they will go fine in more also. Still I have removed get_brands now to avoid any confusion

Comment: I did not ask to post the complete code, Anyway your problem is as I said: `document.getElementById("dn_options")` only works in the first row because you have duplicate IDs - instead use relative addressing (parentNode.parentNode...)

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, I understood that using IDs, it will pick up only 1st row element, with class name it will pick only last row. but how can I refer to the current row element?

Comment: Hey, is there any way rowIndex can help here?

Comment: Yes. `document.querySelector("table:nth-child"+rowindex+" select")`

Comment: I am creating everything through divs. can you suggest a code please.

Comment: Sorry, doc:nth-child

Comment: Again sorry, it is not clear how you want me to update this line of code:  document.getElementById("dn_options").innerHTML=this.responseText;

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Note the change to the HTML IDs too

```js
var currentRow, 
    xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

function get_dealer_name(sel) {
  currentRow = sel.closest(".row"); // needs a polyfill for IE but works in Chrome, Edge, FX
  var msgbox = document.getElementById('mymsg');
  if (msgbox) msgbox.style.display = 'none';

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      currentRow.querySelector(".dn_options").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dealer_Name.php?q1=" + sel.value, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-sm-2">
    <label>Firm Name</label>
    <select class="form-control" name='dealer_firm[]' onchange="get_dealer_name(this)" required>
      <option value="">Select Firm</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-2">
    <label>Dealer Name</label>
    <div class="dn_options">
      <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```